# Returning an $http request into another one after an action

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I cannot seem to get this to work and really starting to get to me. It's very simple.

```
<div ng-app="" ng-controller="customersController">
    <button ng-click="clickLoad()">click</button>
    <ul>
        <li ng-repeat="x in names">
            <button ng-click="showMore($index)">show more</button>
            {{ x.Name + ', ' + x.Country }}
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>

<script>
function customersController($scope, $http) {

    $scope.clickLoad = function() {
        $http.get("http://www.w3schools.com//website/Customers_JSON.php")
            .success(function(response) {
                $scope.names = response;
            });
    }


    $scope.showMore = function(n) {

        $http.get("http://www.w3schools.com//website/Customers_JSON.php")
            .success(function(data) {
                $scope.next = data
            });

        $scope.names.splice(n, 0, $scope.$next);

    }
}
</script>
```

I just want to return a new $http request into the first array (at a certain point). but I don't know how to simply read the data from the second request in anyway shape or form.. I must have the syntax wrong or something.

Comment: You use both `$scope.next` and `$scope.$next`. I guess that's not what you're trying to do. Also, I would put that splice inside the `success` function, because the http call will run aync, so ther'es no guarantee `$scope.next` is set at the time it reaches the `splice`.

Answer (score 2):

Refactor the splice to be inside the success callback

```
$scope.showMore = function(n) {

    $http.get("http://www.w3schools.com//website/Customers_JSON.php")
        .success(function(data) {
            // log the data
            $scope.next = data;
            console.log('data that comes back', data); // what comes back in data?

            // try splice
            $scope.names.splice(n, 0, $scope.$next);
            console.log('after splice', $scope.names);

            // try concat instead?
            $scope.names.concat(data);
            console.log('after concat', $scope.names);
        });
}
```

You can think of this as like timeouts, even though you declare `.splice` after the `.success`, it will still finish the current function and then run the success even if your response time is 0ms, it's just how event queues work.

Meaning, `.success` runs after `.splice` the way you have it and hence it needs to be inside the success callback function.

Also, change your `ng-repeat="x in names"` to

```
ng-repeat="x in names track by $index"
```

There might be a break in the code due to duplicates.

**Update**

In terms of 'returning' something, the function you have returns a promise, so you would need to access it like you would any async task, with a callback or a promise chain.

```
$scope.showMore = function(n) {
    var deferred = $q.defer(); // a deferred object; a unit of work to be done which has callbacks
    $http.get("w3schools.com//website/Customers_JSON.php").then(function(successResponse) { // you can use .then instead of success
        var data = successResponse.data;
        console.log('success response data:', data);
        $scope.names.splice(n + 1, 0, {
            Name: 'John',
            Country: 'Doe'
        });
        deferred.resolve(successResponse); // mark as successful, pass in response as part of resolution. You can replace successResponse with any other data you want, like $scope.names and it will be available in the next step of the promise chain
    }, function(errorResponse){
        var data = errorResponse.data;
        console.log('error response data:', data);
        deferred.reject(errorResponse); // mark as failed, pass in error response which came from server
    });
    return deferred.promise; // return a promise
}
```

Use:

```
// this function will do all processing above and then continue with this one below.
$scope.showMore().then(function(successfulResponse){ // show more will return a promise
    console.log('successfulResponse', successfulResponse); 
}, function(errorResp){
    console.log('errorResp', errorResp); 
});
```

Comment: I did try putting the splice inside the .get. Still does not work. I don't know how to just simply display the result or the data on the request.

Comment: @DanCzarnik, I added some logging above, can you tell me the results of each log?

Comment: also, add 'track by $index' in your code for the repeat

Comment: $scope.showMore = function(n) {

    $http.get("http://www.w3schools.com//website/Customers_JSON.php")
  .success(function(response) {$scope.names.splice(n+1,0,{Name:'John',Country:'Doe'});});
}

I want it to go something like this I just can't get the result to return..

Comment: what do you mean by 'return'? you want the result to be stored somewhere?

Comment: I updated my answer as async calls return promieses, rather than storing a result. Other than that, maybe you can setup a plunker/jsfiddle to demo the issue more clearly